# Get attribute from related table as foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have a contoller which returns all tickets. There is a field `user_id`, which is foreign key to `User` model. When I request to api, I want to get not only user_id also get name.

```
public function index() : TicketsResourceCollection
{
    $tickets = Ticket::all();

    return new TicketsResourceCollection($tickets);
}
```

Ticket migration:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Would reading the [documentation on relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) be of any help? Have you set up relations?

Answer (score 0):

In your ticket model:

```
public function user() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket');
}
```

In your user model:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

That way you can get the tickets with users:

`$tickets = Ticket::all()->with('users');`

Or you can get all tickets for a specific user:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$tickets = $user->tickets;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to not define a relationship:

```
$tickets = Ticket::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ticket.user_id')->where('ticket.user_id', 1)->select('ticket.*', 'users.*')->get();
```

But I would suggest using a laravel relationship is good stuff.

> https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships